# filtering multidimensional array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement multi tabs. Where one tab will have another array of SubClauses. So basically am trying to implement on each tab click setting tabIndex and then filtering out the result based on key match. One tab can have subtabs but others don't have.

```
  tabIndex= 1
     let currentSubClauses: any;
     let innerTabs: any;
     currentSubClauses = responseArray.subClauses.filter((item) => {
      if (item.subClauses && item.subClauses.length > 0) {
        innerTabs= item.subClauses.filter((subItem) => {
          return subItem.tabNumber === this.tabIndex;
       })
       return innerTabs;
      } else {
         return item.tabNumber === this.tabIndex;
     }
   });
```

Expected result: currentSubClauses should hold current tab/subTab data.

What am I doing wrong here?

JSON srtructure -

```
      [
       {
       "clauseCode": "Clause 21(a)",
       "clauseDescription": null,
       "clauseId": 20190152,
       "tabNumber": 1,
       "subClauses": [
       {
       "clauseCode": "Advertisement Expenses",
       "clauseDescription": "some decription",
       "clauseId": 20190153,
        "subClauses": null,
       "orderNumber": 1,
       "tabNumber": 1,
       "questions": [
      
       ],
    
      },
  {
    "clauseCode": "Capital Expenses",
    "clauseDescription": "Capital Expenditure",
    "clauseId": 20190154,
    "subClauses": null,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "tabNumber": 2,
    "questions": [
      
    ],
    
    },
    {
    "clauseCode": "sub tab-3",
    "clauseDescription": "Capital Expenditure",
    "clauseId": 20190154,
    "subClauses": null,
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "tabNumber": 3,
    "questions": [
      
    ],
    
   }
  ]
 },
 {
   "clauseCode": "Clause 21(g)",
   "clauseDescription": null,
   "clauseId": 20190161,
   "subClauses": null,
   "orderNumber": 1,
   "tabNumber": 2,
   "questions": [
  
   ],

  },
 {
  "clauseCode": "Clause 21(f)",
  "clauseDescription": null,
  "clauseId": 20190161,
  "subClauses": null,
  "orderNumber": 1,
  "tabNumber": 3,
  "questions": [
  
   ],

  }
 ]
```

Note- Basically 1st array has subClauses array which has 3 children that am using to display subtabs. tabs which has subCLauses has no children simply added as null .

Comment: Can you post the full code, including responseArray?

Comment: Hard to know what might be happening without seeing the data you're drawing from.

Comment: Provide the response structure and expected output .

Comment: added JSON response. output should be currentSubClauses variable should hold current tab array. if current tab has sub tab then it should hold subtab array